# How can I declare a generic function that returns its params with an additional prop

Tags: typescript

I am writing an index.d.ts file to go along with a module I am declaring.

I have a function that takes an object of a generic type adds an additional property and returns that object so I wanted to have the function as a generic where the inputted type is T and the return is an extended T - the below code is a compiler error because you can't extend like that but is where I got to so far

```
export function addKoCharacterCounter<T>(object:T): {
    count: KnockoutObservable<Number>
} extends T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export function addKoCharacterCounter<T>(object: T): { count: KnockoutObservable<Number> } & T;
```